# getDisplay and getOrientation doesn't detect the TextView

Tags: android, kotlin

The trouble of my code is I am trying to replace the deprecated code `windowManager.defaultDisplay.orientation` and using the suggested code, which will be displayed here [getDisplay()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context.html#getDisplay()) and [getRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/Display#getRotation()), I read carefully what it wanted me to do and in order to be sure that is working, I made a TextView in XML to show if the rotation is correct, to display a string from the TextView. However it doesn't show the string as suggested it to do and I am really not certain or confident that I made the format correctly and don't know how to make it in the correct way to make it work. If anyone has any idea how it should be done, please let me know and if I didn't explained it very well, please do let me know. Thank you in advance.

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/previewView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureButton"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orientationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/orientation"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rollLabel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orientationText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/orientation_goes_here"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rollText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/orientationLabel"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The onCreate() is where I cast the methods below:

```
val displayManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
                        val rotation = getRotation()

                        val orientationWM = when (displayManager.getDisplay(rotation)) {
                            getDisplay(Surface.ROTATION_0) -> orientationView.text = "Portrait"
                            getDisplay(Surface.ROTATION_90) -> orientationView.text = "Landscape"
                            getDisplay(Surface.ROTATION_180) -> orientationView.text = "Rev.Portrait"
                            getDisplay(Surface.ROTATION_270) -> orientationView.text = "Rev.Landscape"
                            else -> "Error"
                        }
```

The methods:

```
fun getDisplay(displayID: Int): Display? {
        val displayManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
     return displayManager.getDisplay(displayID)
}

fun getRotation(): Int {
    val source = 0

    when (source) {
        0 -> Surface.ROTATION_0
        1 -> Surface.ROTATION_90
        2 -> Surface.ROTATION_180
        3 -> Surface.ROTATION_270
        }
    return source
}
```